# IPv6 configuration on Debian with /48 subnet and PtP address?

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6

(I've asked this question before at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72842/ipv6-configuration-on-debian-with-48-subnet-and-ptp-address but it got closed as off-topic and I was redirected here)

I'm sorry to bother you which such a simple (?) question, but I haven't found anything useful on the internet. I'm not very familiar with IPv6 networks, especially when it's not a normal address/netmask/gateway configuration.

To configure IPv6 on a server, I got an IPv6 address range 2a0d:xxxx:2xxx::/48 and another address with the title "PtP" that is 2a0d:xxxx:1xxx::1/127 (I've marked the difference in the addresses in bold) from the guy who configured the hardware and cables. Contact is difficult right now, cannot ask the quy for help at the moment.

I've tried to use the second address as gateway, but since it's in a different subnet, this cannot work. I also tried to use the ::1 of the /48 subnet as gateway (as I thought the '1' from the second address is a typo), which doesn't work either.

I think PtP should mean something like point to point? Is this some kind of 6in4 tunnel or is there another way to configure this IPv6 addresses on the server? Or (and that's my guess) is the configuration incorrect/missing something? (I'm using Debian 10 on this server)

Edit: I was asked to provide the current contents of /etc/network/interfaces file. /etc/network/interfaces.d folder is empty.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enoX inet manual # there are some unused internal network interfaces

auto enp101s0f0
iface enp101s0f0 inet static 
  address x.y.z.2 
  netmask 255.255.255.240 
  gateway x.y.z.1
```

There's nothing wrong with IPv4 connectivity, I just don't know how to add the IPv6 configuration if I don't have the gateway IPv6 address but only this other "PtP" IPv6 address.

In the meantime I've also tried various tunnel options, like a sit v4tunnel, but this also doesn't work either. I think that some of the data I got is wrong.

Comment: What hardware? What cables? Exactly how is this connected to the network?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know that. I've only got the information available in the question.

Comment: Is this a homework question, then?

Comment: No it isn't. I've tried to contact the company who configured the network and set up the hardware now, let's see if the configuration data was wrong or missing something. I've asked the question in the first place because I couldn't find anything on the internet related to this "PtP" address and how to configure that.

Comment: So you don't know what your server is plugged into? How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

File

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

Result config

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enoX inet manual # there are some unused internal network interfaces

auto enp101s0f0
iface enp101s0f0 inet static 
  address x.y.z.2 
  netmask 255.255.255.240 
  gateway x.y.z.1

iface enp101s0f0 inet6 static
  pre-down ip -6 addr flush dev enp101s0f0 scope global || :
  address 2a0d:xxxx:1xxx::1
  netmask 127
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The thing is, I don't have anything in /etc/network/interfaces regarding the IPv6 configuration as I don't know how to configure it. All would be easy if I got the network/subnet and gateway address, however the "PtP" address is not the gateway (as it is also in another subnet). The rest of the /etc/network/interfaces is just the normal configuration for the IPv4 address with auto <ifname>, address, netmask, gateway. IPv4 is working, my problem is that I don't know what I should do with this "PtP" address. Using it as gateway doesn't work.

Comment: I understand you, let's also look at this folder, there are files in which settings may lie `/etc/network/interfaces.d`  (without a network connection you won't be able to connect anywhere)  Run the command to see all active interfaces `ip a`

Comment: The interfaces.d folder is empty. The only thing configures in /etc/network/interfaces is the IPv4:

auto enp...
iface enp... inet static
        address x.y.z.2
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        gateway x.y.z.1

Sorry, somehow multiline/code doesn't work in the comments section. Just for clarification, I set up the server via iDRAC and configured the network, so there's nothing in the files which I didn't put there.

Comment: I need the contents of the `/etc/network/interface` You can change your real IP address to hide

Comment: I've provided the contents of /etc/network/interface in the previous comment (looks like comments don't allow line breaks and better code formatting, sorry).

Comment: Please complete the question, you can use formatting there

Comment: I've edited the question above.

Comment: Most likely I am at the target, I do not know for sure, but now I need the output of the command `ip a` I need to see all the interfaces that use IPv6, as well as how they are configured

Comment: There is no interface configured with IPv6. I want to add the IPv6 configuration, but I don't know how, since I don't have the gateway address of the subnet, I only have this strange "PtP" IPv6 address with subnet /127. I want to add `iface enp101s0f0 inet6 static` but don't know how to put this "PtP" address.

Comment: 2a0d:xxxx:1xxx::1 - this is the gateway

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't. I've already tried this (also wrote that in the question). If I want to add this address as the gateway via `ip -6 route add default via <addr>` it tells me `RTNETLINK answers: No route to host`. Also using the first ::1 address of the /48 subnet I got from the network guy, it doesn't work. Since the address is also titled with "PtP" I would assume that this is some kind of direkt connection (peer to peer) between routers or something.

Comment: I need the output of the command `ip a`